# traversing through HTML DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This piece of html is loaded by an ajax call. There are plenty of such sets of html. This is only 1 set:

```
print '<div id="'.$row['Event ID'].'" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">';

        print '<h5 class="title">'.$row['Title'].'</h5>';
        print '<ul data-role="listview" id="today_events">';
        print '<li class="event"><a href="#">';
        print '<table><tr><td>Date</td>';
        print '<td class="date" style="padding: 10px;">'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
        print '</tr><tr>';
        print '<td> Time </td>';
        print '<td class="time" style="padding: 10px;">'.$row['Time_Duration'].'</td>';
        print '</tr><tr>';
        print '<td> Venue </td>';
        print '<td class="venue" style="padding: 10px;">'.$row['Venue'].'</td>';
        print '</tr></table></a></li>';
        print '<li style="background-color: #CADECC;">';
        print '<button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-calendar" style="width: 170px; float: right; position: relative;">Add to calendar</button>';
        print '</li></ul>'; 

        print '</div>';
```

I am trying to give an alert when the button is clicked. The alert should contain the title and date of the specific `$row` of data.

This is my jQuery code (BUT its not working. I see a blank alert):

```
$("body").on('click','button',function(){
    var title = $(this).closest("div").find(".title").text();
    var date =  $(this).closest("table").find(".date").text();
    //var time =  $(this).parents().find(".time").text();
    //var venue = $(this).parents().find(".venue").text();

    alert(title+date);
    });
```

Comment: In general, when asking for help with a purely client-side issue, it's best to show the generated HTML rather than the server-side code that generates the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line getting the title is fine. The line getting the date is looking for an ancestor element of the button that's a table, but the button isn't *in* the table, it's just in the div that the table's in. So:

```
var date =  $(this).closest("div").find("table .date").text();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/nitit/1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="event1" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">

<h5 class="title">Event Title One</h5>
<ul data-role="listview" id="today_events">
<li class="event"><a href="#">
<table><tr><td>Date</td>
<td class="date" style="padding: 10px;">01/01/2014</td>
</tr><tr>
<td> Time </td>
<td class="time" style="padding: 10px;">1 hour</td>
</tr><tr>
<td> Venue </td>
<td class="venue" style="padding: 10px;">One Plaza</td>
</tr></table></a></li>
<li style="background-color: #CADECC;">
<button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-calendar" style="width: 170px; float: right; position: relative;">Add to calendar</button>
</li></ul>

</div>

<div id="event2" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">

<h5 class="title">Event Title Two</h5>
<ul data-role="listview" id="today_events">
<li class="event"><a href="#">
<table><tr><td>Date</td>
<td class="date" style="padding: 10px;">02/02/2014</td>
</tr><tr>
<td> Time </td>
<td class="time" style="padding: 10px;">2 hours</td>
</tr><tr>
<td> Venue </td>
<td class="venue" style="padding: 10px;">Two Plaza</td>
</tr></table></a></li>
<li style="background-color: #CADECC;">
<button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-calendar" style="width: 170px; float: right; position: relative;">Add to calendar</button>
</li></ul>

</div>

<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    $("body").on('click','button',function(){
      var title = $(this).closest("div").find(".title").text();
      var date =  $(this).closest("div").find("table .date").text();
      //var time =  $(this).parents().find(".time").text();
      //var venue = $(this).parents().find(".venue").text();

      alert(title+date);
    });
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @stud91: With the given HTML and code, it will (as you can see from the example). If you're not even seeing the title, then either your HTML or your code isn't as shown. In any case, the example shows how to do it, you should be able to apply that to your code.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to go up to your ancestor element I would prefer `.parents` instead of `.closest`, so it would be like this:

```
var title = $(this).parents("div").find(".title").text();
var date =  $(this).parents("div").find("table .date").text();
```