# Unable to get HTML DOM element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the text of one of the elements and show it up on an alert but its not working for me. The element in question is `<h5 class="title">`. Here is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-iconpos="none" data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h2><img src="today_calendar.png" style="height: 60px; vertical-align:middle;"> Today's Events</h2>
    <div id="todayCollapsible">

    <div id="event1" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">

    <h5 class="title">Event Title One</h5>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="today_events">
    <li class="event"><a href="#">
    <table><tr><td>Date</td>
    <td class="date" style="padding: 10px;">01/01/2014</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td> Time </td>
    <td class="time" style="padding: 10px;">1 hour</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td> Venue </td>
    <td class="venue" style="padding: 10px;">One Plaza</td>
    </tr></table></a></li>
    <li style="background-color: #CADECC;">
    <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-calendar" style="width: 170px; float: right; position: relative;">Add to calendar</button>
    </li></ul>

    </div>

    <div id="event2" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">

    <h5 class="title">Event Title Two</h5>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="today_events">
    <li class="event"><a href="#">
    <table><tr><td>Date</td>
    <td class="date" style="padding: 10px;">02/02/2014</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td> Time </td>
    <td class="time" style="padding: 10px;">2 hours</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td> Venue </td>
    <td class="venue" style="padding: 10px;">Two Plaza</td>
    </tr></table></a></li>
    <li style="background-color: #CADECC;">
    <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-calendar" style="width: 170px; float: right; position: relative;">Add to calendar</button>
    </li></ul>

    </div>

    </div>
</div>  

<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    $("body").on('click','button',function(){
      var title = $(this).closest("div").find(".title").text();
      var date =  $(this).closest("div").find("table .date").text();
      //var time =  $(this).parents().find(".time").text();
      //var venue = $(this).parents().find(".venue").text();

      alert(title+date);
    });
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/efW2k/

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/37h5Z/   Is your code in body after html as shown? If not use `$(function)({  /* code */ })`

Comment: I think the only way this code would fail is if you don't include jQuery in your `<head>`. That actually caught me while making the fiddle.

Comment: This question involves code that's remarkably similar to code in [this question from just a short time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841834/traversing-through-html-dom-elements-in-jquery/24841872#24841872).

Comment: @parchment it could also fail if any JS errored out before loading the body too

Comment: @Pointy yes im took it from the answer and its not working

Comment: @Pointy sometimes you make me laugh. Sometimes :)

Comment: @parchment I have uploaded my entire code. Please take a look

Comment: @user3760741 go ahead and create a username while you're waiting for an answer. You've obviously at least read another question here before asking one yourself

Comment: @user3760741 well as others have demonstrated by copying your code into jsfiddle, the code does work. What's going wrong? What exactly is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: @Pointy the alert only shows date. No sign of title

Comment: @Pointy please try it locally instead of fiddle

Comment: See the answers about jQuery Mobile below. You can figure out these things by using the DOM inspector in your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that since you are using jQuery mobile, it is restructuring the DOM and wrapping an extra `<dv>` around your `<ul>`

Thus the `closest('div')` is different than the one in your source.

Try This:

Add `data-title` to your h5

```
<h5 class="title" data-title="Event Title Two">Event Title Two</h5>
```

And change JS to:

```
$("body").on('click','button',function(){
  var title = $(this).closest("div").siblings('h5.title').data("title");
  var date =  $(this).closest("div").find("table .date").text();
  //var time =  $(this).parents().find(".time").text();
  //var venue = $(this).parents().find(".venue").text();

  alert(title+date);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/A7O3pDEtpysmuRR3lP3w)**</kbd>

Comment: when in doubt inspect the live html, very easy to do

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, jQuery mobile will wrap some elements with a div, in this case, the `<ul data-role="list-view">`. Therefore, running `.closest('div')` will refer to the generated div, instead of the one that contains the `h5`.

To fix this, add your own class to the div.

```
<div id="event1" class="event-wrapper" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<!--             ^ Here                                                           -->
```

Then, use your class to refer to it.

jQuery mobile adds a further complication: it adds extra text that will be read by the `.text()` function. We need to store the text we need first before jQuery mobile adds text to the page.

```
$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function(){
    $('h5').each(function(){this.dataset.text = this.innerHTML;});
});
```

Then, we need to read the text we need from a data attribute instead of using `.text()`.

```
var title = $(this).closest(".event-wrapper").find(".title").data('text');
var date =  $(this).closest(".event-wrapper").find("table .date").text();
```

Comment: still extra crap in the text though due to a span that gets added also

Comment: @charlietfl Oh, so that's why you bothered to add the `data-title` thing... Thank you, and I guess you got the right answer!

Comment: @parchment..exactly, i wanted to do `text()` also and found more than expected

Answer (score -1):

I've updated my answer. your code works fine. my bad. hehehe.

```
$("body").on('click','button',function(){
   var title = $(this).closest("div").find(".title").text();
   var date =  $(this).closest("div").find("table .date").text();
   //var time =  $(this).parents().find(".time").text();
   //var venue = $(this).parents().find(".venue").text();

  alert(title+date);
}
```